# Octopus deploy and Ubuntu permission

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions, octopus-deploy

After I changed the default user "root" of the installed Octopus Tentancle Service (systemd) to the "ubuntu" user I'm facing the permission error below:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/etc/octopus/My_Tentacle/Tools/Calamari.linux-x64/12.1.1/Calamari': Operation not permitted
```

I have tried to execute the commands below and then restart the service / the entire server afterwards:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /etc/octopus/My_Tentacle/Tools/Calamari.linux-x64/12.1.1/Calamari

sudo chmod -R a+rwx /etc/octopus/
```

But it still doesn't work - the second I change the user of the service back to root again and restart it works again... But it should be best not to execute anything as root - right? So what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just spun up a 2020.04 instance to test this, and did get the same error. This stems from Calamari being installed as the root user initially. After I changed the service to run as my `ubuntu` user, I just deleted `/etc/octopus/<instancename>/Tools/Calamari.linux-x64` and then attempted a deployment - this pushed out Calamari and installed it as the new service user, and all worked as intended! I hope this helps!

Comment: It did indeed! :) Thank you so much! https://www.screencast.com/t/e7cHHpXw3
It would be a great help to other users if this action was mentioned when the error occurs in OD when a deploy fails due to a permission-issue. I was running the latest version of Calamari. You really have to be aware: In my case OD deploys all my app and then a OD step run and start each app via PM2 - but because the PS script is executed by OD the app(s) run as root - but after a reboot they all run as "ubuntu" because PM2 is set to this user or after a reboot and some deploys they would be mixed (root and ubuntu)